# Scala dataset map fails with exception No applicable constructor/method found for zero actual parameters

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have the following case classes

```
case class FeedbackData (prefix : String, position : Int, click : Boolean,
                         suggestion: Suggestion,
                         history : List[RequestHistory],
                         eventTimestamp: Long)

case class Suggestion (clicks : Long, sources : List[String], ctr : Float)

case class RequestHistory (timestamp: Long, url: String)
```

I use it to perform a map operation on my dataset

```
sqlContext = ss.sqlContext
import sqlContext.implicits._


val input: Dataset[FeedbackData] = ss.read.json("filename").as(Encoders.bean(classOf[FeedbackData]))

input.map(row => transformRow(row))
```

At runtime I see the exception

```
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.codehaus.commons.compiler.CompileException: File 'generated.java', Line 24, Column 81: failed to compile: 

No applicable constructor/method found for zero actual parameters; candidates are: "package.FeedbackData(java.lang.String, int, boolean, package.Suggestion, scala.collection.immutable.List, long)"
```

What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Context is fine here, issue with case class, Scala long (Long) have to used instead of Java long (long):

```
case class A(num1 : Long, num2 : Long, num3 : Long)
```

Comment: actually was using Scala Long itself. have edited the question with the actual data structures. also confirmed that the issue isn't with the test setup, so probably something related to the data structure but not sure what is the issue

Comment: if such line "input.show(false)" used instead of "input.map(..", all working fine?
Also such construction can be used for convert DataFrame to DataSet: ".json("filename").as[FeedbackData]"

Comment: yes. changing to .as[FeedbackData] has got it working. whats the theoretical difference here ?

Comment: also to work on nested data structures as in above, using map functions is the only object oriented way right ? through UDFs, the actual suggestion and history attributes are exploded within row object and hence operating on them requires using getByIndex which isn't very clean.

Map Functions have a huge performance penalty due to deserialisation costs but don't see a way out here

Comment: ".as[FeedbackData]" is a official way to create DataSets, here details: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-getting-started.html#creating-datasets

Comment: dataset of objects can be converted to DataFrame by command "input.toDF()", and DataFrame has big number of functions for columns manipulation. Also conversion to DataFrame can be done without ".toDF", DataSet has methods which produce DataFrame, like select: 'input.select("prefix")'.

Answer (score 0):

Inspired from @pasha701,use case could be

```
case class Student(id: Int, name: String)
import spark.implicits._
val df = Seq((1, "james"), (2, "tony")).toDF("id", "name")
df.printSchema()
df.as[Student].rdd.map{
      stu=>
        stu.id+"\t"+stu.name
    }.collect().foreach(println)
```

output:

```
root
  |-- id: integer (nullable = false)
  |-- name: string (nullable = true)

1   james
2   tony
```

reference:https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.0/sql-getting-started.html